# How to enable pep8.E501 fixing on file formatting shortcut?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pep8

When I'm using `Ctrl+Shift+I` shortcut it fixes all errors like invalid count of blank lines. But E501 (too long line) is not fixing. Line saves its length. I've found solutions for ignoring that error but I'd like to translate file to PEP8 fully. How to do it?